# Why is the integral $\int_0^1t\,dW_t$ a normal random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider the random variable $X=\int_0^1t\,dW_t$, where $W_t$ is a Wiener process. The expectation and variance of $X$ are
$$E[X]=E\left[\int_0^1t\,dW_t\right]=0,$$
and $$
Var[X]=E\left[\left(\int_0^1t\,dW_t\right)^2\right]=\int_0^1t^2\,dt=\left.\frac{1}{3}t^3\right|_0^1=\frac{1}{3}.$$

A typical textbook, like Klebaner's one, concludes that the random variable $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and standard variation $1/\sqrt{3}$. However, two moments cannot lead to the conclusion that $X$ is a normal random variable.

So, here is my question: How to prove that $X$ is normal? Is is necessary to calculate all moments of $X$ and to compare them with those of a normal distribution? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: "Fima" = Klebaner?

Comment: Yes, "Fima" = Fima Klebaner. But I must say sorry to Fima because he did give a complete proof using moment method in Example 6.3 in his book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach (which I outline) is via Ito's formula. Define $I_t=\int_0^t s\,dW_s$ for $t\ge 0$, and compute the characteristic function of $I_t$. By Ito:
$$
\exp(i\lambda I_t)=1+i\lambda\int_0^t \exp(i\lambda I_s)s\,dW_s-{\lambda^2\over 2}\int_0^t \exp(i\lambda I_s)s^2\,ds.\tag1
$$
Write $g(s):=\Bbb E[\exp(i\lambda I_s)]$. Take expectations in (1):
$$
g(t)=1-{\lambda^2\over 2}\int_0^t g(s)s^2\,ds,\qquad t\ge 0. 
$$
Now differentiate with respect to $t$ to see that $g$ solves the initial value problem
$$
g(0)=1,\qquad g'(t)=-{\lambda^2t^2\over 2}g(t),\quad t\ge 0.
$$
Therefore $g(t) = \exp(-t^3\lambda^2/6)$ for $t\ge 0$. In particular, for $t=1$, the random variable $I_1$ has characteristic function
$\Bbb E[\exp(i\lambda\int_0^1 s\,dW_s)]=\exp(-\lambda^2/6)$, which means that $\int_0^1 s\,dW_s\sim\mathscr N(0,1/3)$.

Comment: It is brilliant to use the characteristics function which contains all orders of moments of $I_t$ as a powerful tool in the well presented proof. It provides me a new way of thinking on determining a distribution of a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the definition of the stochastic integral as a limit of integrals of step functions. The integral of a step function is a linear combination of independent normal variables.

Comment: That is a good idea. Do you imply using the central limit theorem? By the definition of Ito integral. The random variable can be written as $X_t=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} t_i(W_{i+1}-W_i)$. Certainly the incremental parts of Wiener process $B_{i+1}-B_i$ are independent normal variable. But the increasing factor $t_i$ will ruin the condition of independent and identical distributed (i.i.d) condition under which the central limit theorem can be safely applied.

Comment: You do not need the CLT because the individual terms in the sum are already Gaussians. The density of the sum of independent continuous variables is the convolution of their densities.

Comment: I think the piece that @DavidWu is missing is the fact that a limit (in probability, or even in distribution) of normal random variables is again a normal random variable.  You might want to explain this fact (and maybe how to prove it) in your answer.

Comment: Yes, the CLT is not necessary and I misunderstand your point. Because of the definition of Wiener process, all the $t_i\Delta W_i$ are independent normal random variables. And the sum of finite is still normal. when $n$ goes infinity, the sum of accountable random variables, defined to be the integral, will be normal as well. Thanks for @NateEldredge to point out the limit situation which is very interesting to think carefully.